# Need marquee text but in which we can stop on mouseover

Tags: jquery, marquee

Can you please send it to me in jquery?

Comment: 1995 called. It wants its deprecated HTML tags back :)

Comment: As Asaph suggested, you shouldn't really be using these tags at all, unless you're specifically intending something like a stock ticker.  Even then, there are better ways to provide that kind of information.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [marquee](http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/) jQuery plugin.

```
$('#some-id').marquee().mouseover(function () { 
      $(this).trigger('stop');
   }).mouseout(function () {
      $(this).trigger('start');
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Why can't your use html marquee itself? Its very simple solution with plain javascript.

```
<marquee direction="left" width="750" height="25" scrollamount="3" scrolldelay="10" 
    onmouseover="this._scrollAmount='0'" onmouseout="this._scrollAmount='3'">
Website Hits crossed 1.1 Million, Since 1st March 2006.
</marquee>
```

Will this help?

Comment: Never, ever use this tag.  Ever.